# fs.createWriteStream on error event does not catch errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, fs

I'm trying to upload images from a url to the server safely.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path')

var download = function(url, dest, filename, cb) {
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest + "/" + filename + path.extname(url));

    var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
        response.pipe(file);
        file.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            file.end();
        });
        file.on('finish', function() {
            file.close(cb);
        });
    }).on('error', function(err) { // Handle errors
        fs.unlink(dest);
        if (cb) cb(err.message);
    });
}

var url = "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/spongebob/images/d/d7/SpongeBob_stock_art.png";

download(url, 'downloadedAssets/imgs', 'spongebob', function onComplete(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    } else {
        console.log('image uploaded to server');
    }
});
```

Which crashes the server

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL]: Protocol "https:" not supported.
>   Expected "http:"

I understand I can't upload **https** files, but why does it crash the server instead of executing file.on('error') then ending the file.

I also tried **try/catch** and same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It crashes at `http.get(url,function(){..})` because you are using `http` module. You need to use `https` module to do the get request to a `https` url.

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://encrypted.google.com/', (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });

}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
```

You can use `request` module which support both `http` and `https`. From the [doc](https://github.com/request/request):

> Request is designed to be the simplest way possible to make http
>   calls. It supports HTTPS and follows redirects by default.const request = require('request');

```
const options = {
  url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/request/request',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'request'
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    const info = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(info.stargazers_count + " Stars");
    console.log(info.forks_count + " Forks");
  }
}

request(options, callback);
```

Or to use Promises out of the box, use `axios`.

Comment: ohh I see. Thanks! What if I want the user to be able to upload both http and https. Should I just rewrite the .get call for each of them, or is there a more efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

fs.createWriteStream is working absolutely fine so it is not throwing exceptions or errors.

The error is coming from http.get() method because you are trying to access 'https' using http module. Put debugger in http.get() module, you will definitely get error thrown.